# CSRF tokem for submit form

Tags: php, forms, session, csrf

I'm generating a form submission security token in software.

The idea is to generate a token as soon as the user arrives on the page hosting the form

Allow the user to fill in the form

And only if the token initialized as soon as the user landed on the page is the same as the one in an input field, then run the code, otherwise no

This is to avoid CSRF

Methodology

1: Create a function that generates a token | create a file: config.php

```
function RandomToken($length = 32){
    if(!isset($length) || intval($length) <= 8 ){
        $length = 32;
    }
    if (function_exists('random_bytes')) {
        return bin2hex(random_bytes($length));
    }
    if (function_exists('mcrypt_create_iv')) {
        return bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv($length, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
    }
    if (function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes')) {
        return bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length));
    }
}

function Salt(){
    return substr(strtr(base64_encode(hex2bin(RandomToken(32))), '+', '.'), 0, 44);
}

$token =  (RandomToken())."\n".Salt()."\n";
```

2: include config.php, in the file hosting the form

3: write the rules

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['t'] = $token;


        if ( ($_SESSION['t'] === $_POST['csrf_token_p']))
        {
          /* write code if this is correct */
        }else{
              /* write code if this it's not correct */
             }
    }
```

4: write the form

```
<form action="page.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="csrf_token_p" value="<?php echo $token ?>">
<input name="submit" value="modifica" type="submit">
</form>
```

error: I always get that the two tokens do not match. why?

**edit part**

config.php

```
<?php ob_start(); session_start();
/*
 * https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php
 * funzione per la creazione di un codice unico contro i CSRF attack
 * */


function RandomToken($length = 32){
    if(!isset($length) || intval($length) <= 8 ){
        $length = 32;
    }
    if (function_exists('random_bytes')) {
        return bin2hex(random_bytes($length));
    }
    if (function_exists('mcrypt_create_iv')) {
        return bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv($length, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
    }
    if (function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes')) {
        return bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length));
    }
}

function Salt(){
    return substr(strtr(base64_encode(hex2bin(RandomToken(32))), '+', '.'), 0, 44);
}

$token =  (RandomToken())."\n".Salt()."\n";

session_start();
$_SESSION['t'] = randomToken();

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

form-page.php

```
<?php ob_start(); session_start();
include '../connection/cnt.php';
?>
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

        session_start();
        if (!empty($_POST))
        {
            if (!array_key_exists('csrf_token_p', $_POST))

            {
                $_POST['t'] = null;

                ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    window.location = "p_tl.php?edit=Y";
                </script>
            <?php


            }

            if ($_SESSION['t'] !== $_POST['csrf_token_p'])
            {
            // BAD TOKEN! BAD!
            ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    window.location = "p_tl.php?edit=N";
                </script>
            <?php
            }
        }

    }
    ?>

                    <form id="validate" action="p_tl.php" method="post"  class="needs-validation" novalidate>

                                        <input style="display: " type="text" name="csrf_token_p" value="<?php echo $token ?>" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01"
                                               required>
                                    <input
                                        style="background-color: #9da1a4;color: #fff;"
                                        name="submit"
                                        value="modifica"
                                        class="btn  btn-sm"
                                        type="submit">
                    </form>
```

Comment: tip you should scope the token for a specific form, if you ever intend to have more than one form on the page, your RandomToken token should be a secret and a hash_hmac of that should be the actual token, plus you should use hash_equals for comparison

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['t'] = $token;
```

You need to start the session in config, and create and save the token there. Because *that* is the flow that will create the form. Otherwise, a different session will be opened upon submit.

So:

```
 config.php

 session_start();
 $token = randomToken();
 $_SESSION['t'] = $token;

 print "<form...";
 // In produzione, cambia questo in "hidden", non "text"
 print "<input type=\"text\" name="csrf_token_p" value=\"{$token}\" />";

 // The rest of the form with submit button

 print "</form>";

 form_receive.php

 session_start();
 if (!empty($_POST)) {
     if (!array_key_exists('csrf_token_p', $_POST)) {
         $_POST['t'] = null;
     }
     if ($_SESSION['t'] !== $_POST['csrf_token_p']) {
         // BAD TOKEN! BAD!
         die("Token mismatch");
     }
     // Okay.
```

Comment: however, this does not compare the session token with the form input token

Comment: @user15775524 it actually does: `if ($_SESSION['t'] !== $_POST['t'])` is the comparison.

Comment: @user15775524 I see, I had used the same name for session and post tokens. Names are arbitrary, but I changed it to "csrf_token_p" for clarity.

Comment: sorry friend, I modified my question, with the code you gave me, but it doesn't work, why?

Comment: You are using `$token`, which is **NOT** the output of RandomToken(). Modifying my answer...

Comment: i don't know why not work

Comment: In the file displaying the form, have the value of $_SESSION['t'] displayed. It must be the same as the input field.

Then, in the file receiving the POST, have the value of $_SESSION['t'] displayed. It must be the same value as before.